# Why does the fetchXML Web API url require an entity name?

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetchxml

In order to formulate a FetchXML web request, I have to use the entity name twice, once (in plural form) in the URL and once (in the singular form) in the fetchXML query document:

```
https://abcdef.ghi/fghjkl/api/data/v8.0/transactioncurrencies=<fetch ... <entity name='transactioncurrency'>... >
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am wonder why this is as I feel this is redundant.

The background of the question is that I'd like to submit any fetch-XML document without first parsing it for `entity name='....'` and then use the found entity name in the URL to submit the document.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definitive answer but it's probably required by the OData specifications, keep in mind that in this specific query the fetchxml is a parameter, it doesn't define (explicitly) the entity you are operating.

Just a note on the plural/singular forms, most of the time you have the plural, in some cases (custom entities) you get mixed results, in some cases (standard entities) you get a completely different result, like "webresourceset" that is the collection for "webresource" entity.

My opinion? they should have used the singular form inside OData

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help, according to the documentation of CRM, in the web api they use the name of the entity set for make the url. This entity set corresponds with the "LogicalCollectionName" attribute value of the entity's metadata.

You can retrieve this attribute value like this way:

```
  .../api/data/v9.0/EntityDefinitions?$filter=LogicalName eq 'xxxx'&$select=LogicalCollectionName
```

Which would give a result like the following:

```
{"@odata.context":".../api/data/v9.0/$metadata#EntityDefinitions(LogicalCollectionName)","value":[{"LogicalCollectionName":"yyyyy","MetadataId":"guidnumberofthemetada"}]}
```

As they indicated, this name can even be changed to alter how the url is invoked:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/web-api-types-operations#change-the-name-of-an-entity-set

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll be working on that project again on Tuesday, so I hope I can then take a look at it and give you feedback on my findings.

Comment: as pointed out from the documentation, you should always use EntitySetName, most of the time LogicalCollectionName and EntitySetName returns the same value (like for account) but not always (as my example with webresource in my answer, LogicalCollectionName returns webresources and EntitySetName returns webresourceset), for querying OData EntitySetName should be used